# Origin of references to bats flying out of nostrils?

Tags: cultural-phrases

In the **Harry Potter** fandom, there is a curse named [Bat-Bogey Hex](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Bat-Bogey_Hex), that "transforms the target's bogeys into large bats that fly out of the victim's nose".

In the **Friends TV Series** S02E03 right at the beginning of the episode, Chandler breaks up with a girl because her nostrils were so huge that "when she sneezed, bats flew out of them".

What is the origin of the reference to bats flying out of peoples' nostrils in these two cases? Is this just a coincidence or does it actually have some kind of cultural or linguistic origin?

Comment: Reminds me of [*nose goblins*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i5NHx6GhMlQ), [*flying monkeys*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winged_monkeys), and [*bats in the belfry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bats_in_the_belfry).

Comment: @David Why did you edit out ["What's the deal with“](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/What%27s+the+deal%3F) it seems pretty standard English.

Comment: @Mari-LouA. It is slangy and imprecise. My previous suggestion to the poster of editing it was removed, presumably because of a frivolous remark about financial dealings. However if this is site for the English Language we should encourage new posters to write in a formal precise manner. By editing  I demonstrated to the poster how to do this. In my opinion too few long-term members (I realize that you are an exception) take the trouble to do this. Of course, the lack of clarity in questions makes it difficult to ensure one's edit doesn't change the sense, but the OP can amend.

Comment: @David  I can assure you that the English examining board, Cambridge English Language Assessment, favours and encourages the usage of slang, idioms, and phrasal verbs in candidate's informal writing and speaking (as long as it's not vulgar) If someone what to express their astonishment using "What's the deal?" I see no good reason for censoring it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA — As I said it’s imprecise. Either spell out what you mean or, as it’s a title, leave it out. And I have no patience with educationalists shortchanging our children by lowering their aspirations in this way. Our children can do better and we can help them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The association comes from nostrils looking like caves and bats living in caves. In high school, I had some friends who would say "bats in the cave" to let someone know they had visible boogers in their nostrils.

I don't suspect any great cultural or linguistic significance beyond individuals making the same observation about nostrils looking like caves.

Comment: [_Urbandictionary_](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bat%20in%20the%20cave) has the popular _bat(s) in the cave_ reference also.